# angular simple directive not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angular and am very very excited about it.
I am trying to put my top naviagtion into a directive so it can be 1) resuable 2) make my html easier to read

however i can not get my topMenu directive to work for the life of me. is it possible to glance at my fiddle and see what I am doing wrong?
Thanks a million, im losing my hair lol

http://jsfiddle.net/g6pb0m4a/
here is my menu.js file

```
    //define menu controller
 var menu =  angular.module('MenuApp', [])
    menu.controller('MenuCtrl', [function() {
      var self = this;
      self.active= '1';
      self.navigation = [
    {
        menutext:"Home",
        url:"#/"
    },
    {
        menutext:"About App",
        url: "#/aboutapp",
        submenu:[
        {
            menutext:"Pricing",
            url: "#/pricing"
        }
        ]
    }
    ];

  }]);

menu.directive('topMenu', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<h2>test</h2>'
  };
});
```

here is my index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Fit Bit App</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src ="app/controllers/menu.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="MenuApp">
<header>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-ng-controller = "MenuCtrl as menuCtrl">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" data-ng-repeat = "menuitem in menuCtrl.navigation">
            <li ng-if="!menuitem.submenu"><a href={{menutext.url}}>{{menuitem.menutext}}</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown" ng-if="menuitem.submenu"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">{{menuitem.menutext}}<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li data-ng-repeat = "submenu in menuitem.submenu"><a href={{submenu.url}}>{{submenu.menutext}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

</header>

<div><top-menu></top-menu></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to load the scipts on the body or head option in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jL8mq5hc/ . ie. left panel dropdown "no-wrap -in body". Otherwise you end up loading the scripts on the document load by using `load` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is mainly due to the place where you register the app and controller. In your fiddle you are using option `onLoad` so with that jsfiddle will load the scripts in the script panel inside `window.onload` which happens after angular tried to bootstrap the application as it finds `ng-app` directive in the html. Instead of using `onLoad` option use `wrap in body` (or head) option so that scripts in the script panel gets run beforehand angular instantiates your app `MenuApp`.
**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jL8mq5hc/)**

Comment: Now im really confused. it works on fiddle however in my normal app loading on my server it doesnt load the directive. Any idea based on the code what maybe wrong?

Comment: Can't say without knowing what are you doing in your real scenario. You should also look at the errors in the console as well.

Comment: no error message in console, pushed it up to github if you dont mind taking two seconds. something so simple has wasted hours of my time lol
https://github.com/blbraner/fitbitapp

Comment: Take a look at your controllers/menu.js file closely. Your directive is [created inside the controller body](https://github.com/blbraner/fitbitapp/blob/master/app/controllers/menu.js#L30). Move that out and see what happens. app/menu.js looks fine though you could try using that.

Comment: Time to take a break i believe.. :) Do you mind accepting the answer?